# Find the device(IP camera) IP address present in LAN network using iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, ip, lan

I am working on project, which has find the camera IP-address which is connect in LAN network, i am using LAN search for iOS to find the camera, it works but some times camera has self assigned to **(169.254.164.XXX)** default IP address. LAN search can’t find it. How can i find the all camera which is present in LAN network, even though camera in default network?

Answer (score 0):

This will returns local IP Address:

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress {
        NSString *address = @"error";
        struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
        struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
        int success = 0;
        // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
        success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
        if (success == 0) {
            // Loop through linked list of interfaces
            temp_addr = interfaces;
            while(temp_addr != NULL) {
                if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == 2) {
                    // Check if interface is end which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                    if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                        // Get NSString from C String
                        address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                    }
                }
                temp_addr =    temp_addr->ifa_next;
            }
        }
        // Free memory
        freeifaddrs(interfaces);
        return address;
    }
```

Comment: i have my Local IP address, i need all device IP address which connect to my LAN network.